# How to disable preloading next page in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I disable the preloading in a `ViewPager`?

I have a ViewPager with 3 pages. So I don't want to load the next page and previous page. How can I disable this behaviour?

I tried

> viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) says:

> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.

So following code is not work as you expected:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)
```

But there is a trick, You can initilize `view|value` just when `fragment` is visible to user with:

```
 @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
            // do something nice here
        }
    }
```

Comment: where i initilize in (activity or viewPager adapter)

Comment: @user6741232 in your fragments.